# What is the difference between redirection 2>&1 1>file.txt and >a.txt 2>&1?

Tags: linux, redirection

What is the difference between redirection `./prog 2>&1 1>file.txt` and `./prog >a.txt 2>&1`? It looks that `./prog 2>&1 1>file.txt` doesn't save stderr to file but this `./prog >a.txt 2>&1` does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redirection operators are examined left-to-right, thus

```
 foo > bar 2>&1
```

*first* redirects standard-output to `bar` and then redirect standard-error to the location where standard-output is redirected at this point (thus `bar`, too).

```
 foo 2>&1 > bar
```

*first* redirects standard-error to what standard-output points to (most probably the terminal) and then redirects standard-output to `bar`.

Short: first one redirects both `stdout` and `stderr` to `bar`, second one redirects only `stdout` to `bar` and `stderr` to terminal.